# What is the purpose of django tempate tags in the MVC model?

Tags: django, model-view-controller, django-templates, templatetags

It is my understanding that template tags are a way to organize presentation logic, is this correct?

What I want to do is load/read a bunch of my model objects, but show them in different areas of the template according to a filter.

The first thought was to implement a tag get_myobjects_by_filterx but then I have to implement it for each filter I have, and I would use it by calling the tag on the areas of my template where I want them to show up.

So the second thought was to move the filterx into the tag itself, so the call would be get_myobjects_by "X" (passing the filter as string) then in the tag filtering and returning. Is this the prefered way? What if I need to pass another object not just a string?

Could I use a filter instead?

Little more detailed what I want to do: Load a kind of my objects and filter it by some of its fields, depending on which filter is applied, show it in different areas of my template. For example I want "if objects filtered by X show all of those in the column x else in column y and so on".

How do I solve this kind of question with django?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have to filter your contents by your object fields, you should do it in your views and render the result in the template.

Comment: Alrite, so basically I should never filter my objects in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my understanding goes, template tags are nothing but some python functions which can be used inside the templates. Because a django template is not your normal python program.